# ¿Por que no me muestra la información?

Tags: c#

Quiero pasar x cantidad de  información de un archivo txt a un RichTexBox, hice el siguiente código pero no me pasa nada y no me muestra ningún error:

```
public string Readtxt(string path)
{
    string txt= "";
    FileStream objArchivotxt = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader objRead = new StreamReader(objArchivotxt);
    int i = 0;

    while (objRead.EndOfStream)
    {
        txt += objRead.ReadLine();
        i++;

        if (i == 3)
            break;
    }

    objRead.Close();
    objArchivotxt.Close();

    return txt;
}
```

Aquí paso la información al RichTexBox:

```
if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    Texto.Text = objReadtxt(openFileDialog1.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Hola podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron útiles y marcar como aceptada, la que haya resuelto tu problema y darle un voto también si lo deseas, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public string Readtxt(string path)
{
   string texto = "";

   if (File.Exists(path))
   { 
       texto = File.ReadAllText(path);
   }

   return texto
}
```

Debes usar el metodo **ReadAllText** de la clase **File**, aqui lo primero que se hace es verificar si el fichero existe para que no se lance ninguna excepcion, y en caso de que exista se lee todo el contenido del fichero y se guarda en la variable texto, por ultimo se retorna el valor de la variable texto.

Para usar la clase **File** y su metodo **FileReadAllText** debes poner en los using:

```
using System.IO;
```

Para llamar la funcion creada debes poner:

```
 if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
    richTextBox.Text = Readtxt(openFileDialog1.FileName);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu función se llama `Readtxt` y la invocas con `objArchivos`

No esta invocando a tu función.

Si no peta es por que tienes otra función que se llama `objArchivos` en tu código.

Comment: Ya lo corregí y pasa lo mismo

Comment: @Zeiker puedes editar la pregunta, asi no se confudiran los demas

Comment: @Zeiker tienes la opción de debugar?

Comment: No tengo esa opción , ya lo pude hacer haciendo (!objRead.EndOfStream)

Comment: si has cambiado el nombre de la funcion como te dije, y no devuelve nada el posible que no puedas leer el fichero. En vez de hacer un return haz un printf directamente a ver que devuelve, si es blanco es tema del fichero.